# Mathematical Journal on Logic and Set Theory

Tags: logic, reference-request, set-theory, reference-works

I'm looking for free to access mathematical journal about logic and set theory. I found some earlier but all of them need payment/subscription. Is there anyone that know some reference? I'm a little short on money, so I can't afford spending yet. Thank you to those who'd help.

Comment: Can you be more specific in what you are looking for? You can find almost every math book online.

Comment: The majority of works are freely accessible on arXiv.

Answer (score 4):

Why do you want a *journal*? They characteristically publish advanced research level papers.

If you want to learn some logic and set theory, even at grad level, start with some good books. You can download a study guide making suggestions about what to read at https://logicmatters.net/tyl. And, shocking to say, every book mentioned in the guide is available online at the usual PDF repositories. :)